# what is wrong with this code to read specific registry value in a subkey then do a if exist/if not statement

Tags: windows, registry

well with some help from this site and dream in code i fixed my error, but am now the code just plain doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code:

```
using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\"))
if (Key != null)
{
    string val = (string)Key.GetValue("COMODO Internet Security");
    if (val == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("value not found");
    }
    else
    {
        // use the value
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("key not found");
}
```

and when i use it, it give the "value not found" message box like its supposed to if it doesn't exist, only problem is the value DOES exist... i checked manually through regedit. so whats wrong?

Comment: Are you actually executing this code, or is it some service, or else which could have different permissions than you?

Comment: @pascal what it is being used for is: once a specific program closes i want it to check to see if a specific registry value exists, if it does not exist then i want it to delete a specific folder, if it DOES exist i want it to NOT delete that specific folder.

Comment: print the names?  `string[] names = Key.GetValueNames(); string buf="values:"; foreach (string s in names) { buf += s+","; } MessageBox.Show(buf);`

Comment: no i dont actually want to have it do message boxes, thats just for testing  to see if the code is working correctly (and its noT)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have the problem to query registry values of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` key on 64-bit operation system from a 32-bit application. In the case you will see values existion only under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx). If you use unmanaged API (or invoce) you can open Run key with `RegOpenKeyEx` and `KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flags (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129.aspx). You should test whether the application run under 64-bit operation system before using `KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag. In case of 32-bit operation system you should use `KEY_QUERY_VALUE` flag only.